# Insert array BigInt in a column of MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I'm back here again because I need yet another help; I need to know how to insert an array into a column of an existing MySQL table.
my table is called movies, and between the columns there are BigInt fields to which I want to attribute an array of values, I tried by directly inserting the values ​​I wanted between [], but the attempt was not successful, some of you do you know how i should do it?
In the meantime I am attaching a photo of the structure of my table (obtained through the describe movies command in the MySQL terminal) in order to give a better idea of ​​what I mean, obviously if someone also wants to give some other suggestions that can improve the setting given by me at the table I am open to your advice.
The column to which in this specific case I am interested in attributing an array of values ​​is genre_id (BigInt Not Null), at the moment if I attribute only one value the query works, but just as I have already said, many times, I want to insert more values ​​and I ran out of ideas of how to do this.

[image: movies table]

I thank all those who will once again want to give me a hand, always excuse me for the way I speak English.
Good day everyone
Alessandra

Comment: in the screenshot there doesn't seem to be any `array` type column !

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to have more than one value in `genre_id` for each Movie record?

Comment: @HarshGundecha First of all, thank you for your quick reply; so should i change the column type by changing from BigInt to Array ?? if i have to do it how should i do it?

Comment: @matigo thanks to you too for your quick reply; however it is what I want to achieve.

Comment: You cannot do that with a `BIGINT`. By your definition, you can only have one value in the field. If you would like to assign multiple genres to the movie, then you will need another table that links `movie_id` with `genre_id`.

Comment: @matigo In my movies table I have already set up the foreign keys (you can find a capure of this here: https://i.ibb.co/rFJ7Tc5/11.png)

Did I do something wrong in doing this?

Comment: @matigo so the only way I have to solve my problem is to craete a pivot table between my movies table and my genres table?

Comment: @AlessandraCastiglione yes, that's the standard, relational database way of modelling a many-to-many relationship. Please, do some reading on the concept of normalisation, you need that if you would like to work with relational databases.

Comment: thanks a lot to all of you. I'll get to work right away